# How to get a list of values from jQuery inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given the following html:

```
<input type="text" name="imdb_url" /><br/>
<input type="text" name="imdb_url" /><br/>
<input type="text" name="imdb_url" /><br/>
<input type="text" name="imdb_url" /><br/>
```

Is there a one-liner to get an array of the user-entered values? Something like:

```
var items = $('input[name="imdb_url"]'). ??
res = [v1, v2, v3, v4]
```

Comment: have you looked at http://api.jquery.com/serializearray/ ? You could do `var items = $('input[name="imdb_url"]').serializeArray()` and then you'd have pulls like `items[0].value`

Comment: also you don't have values and you might consider looking at http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/ wherein you could do something like `var items = $.map($('input[name="imdb_url"]'), function(v, i){ return v.value; })` then you have pulls like `items[0]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use **`.map()`**:

```
var items = $('input[name="imdb_url"]').map(function(){ return this.value; });
```

While there are other ways, map passes through each matching element, and makes an array-like object based on the `return` of the function inside. You can read more about it **[here](http://api.jquery.com/map/)**.

As [@SpYk3HH](https://stackoverflow.com/users/900807/spyk3hh) mentioned, you can also use [**`$.map()`**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) which works in a slightly different way but is also a good option if you want to get an array instead of an array-like object.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the difference between using `.map` and `.each` ?

Comment: Also, i'd explain to him the difference in both ways. With `$.map` you get a more direct "natural array", whereas with `$(ele).map` you get a jQuery object return which maybe more more than he intends to retrieve. That could be a problem in a for loop, where the jquery method will be evaluated in

Comment: btw, props on quick answer. +1

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
var items =[];$('input[name="imdb_url"]').each(function () {items.push($(this).val());});
```

Which admittedly I'd usually write like:

```
var items = [];
$('input[name="imdb_url"]').each(function() {
    items.push($(this).val());
});
```

but you asked for it on on line :)